# Bind properties of a class to a WPF button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I want to bind 2 properties of a class that are inside of a List in a List to the Content of dynamically generated Button in my WPF program.

This is the XAML I have so far that binds the dynamically generated buttons as a 2D grid

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Button Height="35" Width="35" Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1" IsEnabled="{Binding}" x:Name="fieldButton" Click="fieldClick" Content="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="lst" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}" Margin="0,0,339,0">
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Here is the class that created the Grid and fills the attributes of the class with the correct values

```
class Grid {

    private const int SIZE = 10;
    private List<List<Field>> fields;

    public Grid() {
        fields=new List<List<Field>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            fields.Add(new List<Field>());
            for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                fields[i].Add(new Field(i, j));
            }
        }
    }

    public List<List<Field>> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
}
```

And here is the class that has the filled attributes

```
class Field {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Field(int x,int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Currently the Grid shows ".Field" as Content for every button. I want it to be "x,y" though.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I think you mean _properties_, not _attributes_. Those are totally different things in C#. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `ToString()` override in your *Field* `class` for something more interesting to show up in the `Content`.